# Problems installing and running igraph for Python 2.7.9 Anaconda 2.2.0 Mac osx 10.10.2

Tags: python, igraph

I'm struggling to get igraph successfully installed and running on my Mac.  I'm using Python 2.7.9, Anaconda 2.2.0 on Mac OSX 10.10.2

It appears that I have installed igraph successfully and when I type

```
import igraph
```

or

```
 from igraph import *
```

there are no complaints.

```
print igraph.__version__
```

produces the following output:

```
0.1.6
```

But when I try to use

```
g = igraph.Graph(1)
```

or

```
g = Graph(1)
```

(depending on how I imported) I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Graph'

dir(igraph)
```

Produces the following:

```
['__author__',
 '__builtins__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__license__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '__path__',
 '__title__',
 '__version__',
 'draw',
 'force_directed_layout',
 'generate',
 'json_formatter',
 'notebook',
 'to_json']
```

So presumably I should see graph there as an attribute?

Has anyone else experienced this problem?

Comment: Maybe you just need to change directory. If there is an `igraph` directory in `.`, then that is imported.

Comment: I checked and there is no igraph directory in my working directory

Comment: You installed a different igraph library; you are probably looking for `python-igraph`.

Comment: Thanks @Tamás, turns out you are right that I did not have python-igraph installed (which is what I wanted) - turns out that is a whole other problem so will post as a fresh question